# Need to print only the frame and not the whole page using Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-frame

When I try to print the webpage, only the frame appears in the print when using IE or other browsers. However, through the google chrome, the whole page gets printed.

I have done a little research and found out that adding the [OpenFrame plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kdhjgkkaacdhdioocfbpmhjidbinfajj) would do the trick. However, I am looking for the solution without the plugins. Our product is used by a number of customers and we can't ask them to install any plugins.

Can we fix this by making CSS changes or scripts.

Answer (score 28):

Using JavaScript you can print frames independently, e.g.

```
top.frames[1].print()
```

If you include a print button or listen to [print events](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/), you can call your print function that prints only the frame you want.

Or you can use CSS @media print to set what gets printed

Answer (score 16):

Highlight (select) what you want to print, right-click over the selected area and hit print.

p.s.: No other option worked. The add-on (Chrome app) doesn't have a print option, only open in new window and by doing so it sends a new page request and for many sites it won't work.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use this "[Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-frame/kdhjgkkaacdhdioocfbpmhjidbinfajj)" to add a Context sub-menu to your Chrome.

After the installation right click on the frame you want to print, select [This Frame] and the select the option that fits the best with your situation, usually [Open Frame in New tab].
Once you have the frame in a new tab you simply print it with CTRL-P or Right-Click [Print].

Comment: Really wish this was baked into Chrome

Comment: link is now 404

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print { .div-to-not-print {display:none}}
```

is problematic because

1. It's not an end-user solution; it has to be done by the page
   developer, and
2. We're talking about frames, which are actually independent pages.
        That sort of solution wouldn't allow a user to print two
       frames independently.

The suggestion

```
Click on the File > Print , then use the option Simplify Page
```

may work in some circumstances, but, for me, it just removes all frames and reverts to the `<noframe>` content in the frameset page.

As far as I can tell, there is no decent way to print just one frame in a frameset that is already loaded. A Chrome plugin that I haven't tried called "Print This Frame" really just re-loads the frame in a new tab (with a round-trip to the server).

But, without that plugin, if the frame you want to print was created from a hyperlink *within the frameset*, you can usually load the frame in a separate tab or window just by right-clicking on that link and selecting "Open link in new tab" or "Open link in new window"

Answer (score 0):

Well the only workaround I could suggest is to open the source of the page and find the section

clink on the link and print it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using CSS:

> @media print { .div-to-not-print {display: none} }

In the print version the blocks with class `div-to-not-print` will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I found one another option useful.

Click on the File > Print , then use the option Simplify Page , that does removes useless things from page.

It might not be relevant to specific page you are printing. But i use it often.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem, I found that the most convenient way to control exactly what I wanted to print, thus remove the adds and various elements that just waste paper was to edit the page source directly:

- Inspect the page : Ctrl-Shift-I -> this opens a pane with the source code of the page and the layout
- By hover'ing over the source code it is really quick to identify the interesting elements that you are interested in, just remove the other ones:

  - it is a hierarchical representation of the page layout so you can expand the  and  elements to have more granularity when hover'ing
  - you may need to change or remove the class of the  elements to change the internal layout if you have removed internal columns for example

Here is an example:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

1. Click on the frame of interest
2. press CTRL+A (on Windows or equivalent on Mac) to select all content of the frame
3. press CTRL+P or choose print from the context menu

This should show a preview with everything in the frame ready to be saved as PDF or printed to the printer.